# End to End Monitoring Framework on C3 cloud

Tags: scala, rest, apache-spark, cloud

I need advice on the API's which can be used to do end to end monitoring on the Cloud instance. To give the complete picture, I have a model(R/SQL/Scala) running on C3 instance and i want to do end to end monitoring from data fetch to relevant output from the model. The end to end monitoring also needs to be displayed on a dashboard. The instance i am using is Linux.

When i googled for this, i cam across lots of technologies like Zabbix, AppDynamics etc. which are more sort of products. Is there any existing API which is platform independent and can be integrated with multiple technologies like R/Scala etc? Also,If I am choosing the existing API do i need to be dependent on the developers for implementing that in my model? Or Shall i start from the scratch with REST/SOAP web service?

Any help in this regard will be very much appreciated.